# Trying to sign an XML in perl. Signature not accepted

Tags: xml, perl, security

I'm trying to sign an XML message (in compliance with the XMLdsig specifications) using Perl. I know there are perl modules out there that can do this (like XML::Sig) but both the XML and signature need to comply to a certain set of rules which XML::Sig (or any other module for that matter) can't handle.

I've written a module in Perl and as far as I can tell it *should* work, but the other side (an online payment system) keeps rejecting the signature.

The original XML Message looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DirectoryReq xmlns="http://www.idealdesk.com/ideal/messages/mer-acq/3.3.1" version="3.3.1">
  <createDateTimestamp>2014-02-04T20:01:22.000Z</createDateTimestamp>
  <Merchant>
    <merchantID>100000001</merchantID>
    <subID>1</subID>
  </Merchant>
</DirectoryReq>
```

After signing, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DirectoryReq xmlns="http://www.idealdesk.com/ideal/messages/mer-acq/3.3.1" version="3.3.1">
  <createDateTimestamp>2014-02-04T20:01:22.000Z</createDateTimestamp>
  <Merchant>
    <merchantID>100000001</merchantID>
    <subID>1</subID>
  </Merchant>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>T7GvvEwbwCx3pNGSGiO32iqqOT1Yhcm+HGdBRyL1qfQ=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>
LM1CkBF+eLzkUxzU3/P01JXqA23ZRRLQkd13tN630YqLGRLuPB3Ah1oLbPj7p5JSZPJ+UCSNrHbR
5UYydcP1mNdd4+mIIQwKBQEUKq8i5VV4BYRL+DKewBMT+zctXXNEpBL7TykgVhxjjctmbTs13cuT
Tv+Cx2tcshC5CiK1oj0bU3ESrUjuBmWA4gfniM05SOzEYn4GEl3UTa9M66EWZ0lVg7Y8FNCMXt/1
Mvq+FaCJMOyU5C+LCZ/QSvhrut1CoOyTk+gEOnBxX14INwsnziw1syVa4x/wF3z7gxf5UOsFoIpF
98XGVkLZh1aXRov03zK2qWI+bumKr4Zi+9cbLg==
    </SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <KeyName>6C5D6B7042381F2C249DD982E6A87A3F216CDD82</KeyName>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
</DirectoryReq>
```

Now I know for sure that everything other than the SignatureValue is 100% correct.

As I understand XML signing, only the (exclusive canonicalized version of) `<SignedInfo>` needs to to be signed. So what I do is this:

In Perl:

```
# $digest contains the digest of the message (confirmed to be correct)

my $SignedInfo = <<EOT;
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <DigestValue>$digest</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
EOT

# SignedInfo needs to be signed using RSAWithSHA256

my $dataToSign = _CanonicalizeXML( $signedInfo, 1 ); # Does exclusive canonicalization
my $pkrsa      = Crypt::PK::RSA->new( "priv.pem", $password );
my $sig        = $pkrsa->sign_message( $dataToSign, "SHA256", "v1.5" );

$sig = encode_base64( $sig );
chomp( $sig );
```

The result... an invalid signature.

I'm at a loss as to why. I've checked the output of the canonicalization and it looks ok to me:

```
<SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"> </CanonicalizationMethod>
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></SignatureMethod>
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></DigestMethod>
        <DigestValue>T7GvvEwbwCx3pNGSGiO32iqqOT1Yhcm+HGdBRyL1qfQ=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
```

So what am I doing wrong? Is the output of the canonicalization indeed correct? Am I signing the correct thing? The correct way?

Thanks in advance.